# unable to fire checkbox event in jquery Mobile backbone

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I am developing an app using jquery Mobile and Backbone.
The `click .check : toggleDone` event is not being fired. I dont know the cause. please 
help.

```
var requestItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "label",
template : $("#requestItemTemplate").html(),
events : {
    "click .check" : "toggleDone",
},
toggleDone: function() {
    console.log("clcik");
    this.model.toggle();
},
initialize: function() {
     console.log("requestItemInit");
},
render: function() {
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
    $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));     
    return this;
}});
```

This is my template for the same view

```
<script type='text/template' id='requestItemTemplate'>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class = "check" 
    <%= done ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %> data-theme="e">
    <%= requestorName%> :: <%=requestorEmailId%> : <%= requestorContactNo%>
  </input>
</label>
</script>
```

Comment: try using `append` instead of `html`.  read this for a little bit of background: http://tbranyen.com/post/missing-jquery-events-while-rendering

Comment: No `append` also did not help.
I think, the events for the view are not bound properly. Though i am not able to figure the exact cause.
i am using trigger('create') alongwith `append` to maintain my jqueryMobile styles.

Comment: I wrapped the `<input type = "checkbox">` around a `<button>` and add teh event  `"click .btn_check" : "toggleDone",`
now i am able to use the event. i wonder why its behaving weirdly with the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `click` -- mobile Safari at the least waits 300ms to fire the click event since it's trying to decide as to fire `click` or `dblclick`

You should try listening to `touchend` instead.

(Spine [specifically has info](http://spinejs.com/mobile/docs/events) around not using `click`)

Comment: Thx for sharing the knowledge. Sounds like a gotcha that I should keep in mind, too.